# PHP include() wiping rest of HTML document?

Tags: php, html

So I have a simple html page that looks like this.

```
<html>
<head>
        <?php include("scripts/header.php"); ?>
        <title>Directory</title>
</head>
<body>
        <?php include("scripts/navbar.php"); ?>
        <div id="phd">
                <span id="ph">DIRECTORY</span>
                <div id="dir">
                        <?php include("scripts/autodir.php"); ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!--Footer Below-->
        <?php include("scripts/footer.php"); ?>
        <!--End Footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the problem is, when I load the page, it's all sorts of messed up. Viewing the page source code reveals that everything after `<div id="dir">` is COMPLETELY GONE. The file ends there. There is no included script, no `</div>`'s, footer, or even `</body>`, `</html>`. But it's not spitting out any errors whatsoever. Just erasing the document from the include onward without any reason myself or my buddies can figure out. None of us have ever experienced this kind of strange behavior.

The script being called in question is a script that will fetch picture files from the server (that I've uploaded, not users) and spit out links to the appropriate page in the archive automatically upon page load because having to edit the Directory page every time I upload a new image is a real hassle.

The code in question is below:

```
<?php
    //Define how many pages in each chapter.
    //And define all the chapters like this.
    //const CHAPTER_1 = 13; etc.
    const CHAPTER_1 = 2; //2 for test purposes only.
    //+-------------------------------------------------------+//
    //| DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!!!                         |//
    //+-------------------------------------------------------+//

    //Defining this function for later. Thanks to an anon on php.net for this!
    //This will allow me to get the constants with the $prefix prefix. In this
    //case all the chapters will be defined with "CHAPTER_x" so using the prefix
    //'CHAPTER' in the function will return all the chapter constants ONLY.
    function returnConstants ($prefix) {
            foreach (get_defined_constants() as $key=>$value) {
                    if (substr($key,0,strlen($prefix))==$prefix) {
                            $dump[$key] = $value;
                    }
            }
            if(empty($dump)) {
                    return "Error: No Constants found with prefix '" . $prefix . "'";
            }
            else {
                    return $dump;
            }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------//
    $archiveDir = "public_html/archive";
    $files = array_diff(scandir($archiveDir), array("..", "."));
    //This SHOULD populate the array in order, for example:
    //$files[0]='20131125.png', $files[1]='20131126.png', etc.
    //---------------------------------------------------------//
    $pages = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    //This parses through the files and takes only .png files to put in $pages.
            $parts = pathinfo($file);
                    if ($parts['extension'] == "png") {
                            $pages[] = $file;
                    }
            unset($parts);
    }
    //Now that we have our pages, let's assign the links to them.
    $totalPages = count($pages);
    $pageNums = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
            //This will be used to populate the page numbers for the links.
            //e.g. "<a href='archive.php?p=$pageNum'></a>"
            for($i=1; $i<=$totalPages; $i++) {
                    $pageNums[] = $i;
            }
            //This SHOULD set the $pageNum array to be something like:
            //$pageNum[0] = 1, $pageNum[1] = 2, etc.
    }
    $linkText = array();
    $archiveLinks = array();
    foreach ($pageNums as $pageNum) {
            //This is going to cycle through each page number and
            //check how to display them.
            if ($totalPages < 10) {
                    $linkText[] = $pageNum;
            }
            elseif ($totalPages < 100) {
                    $linkText[] = "0" . $pageNum;
            }
            else {
                    $linkText[] = "00" . $pageNum;
            }
    }
    //So, now we have the page numbers and the link text.
    //Let's plug everything into a link array.
    for ($i=0; $i<$totalPages; $i++) {
            $archiveLinks[] = "<a href='archive.php?p=" . $pageNums[$i] . "'>" . $linkText[$i] . " " . "</a>";
    //Should output: <a href= 'archive.php?p=1'>01 </a>
    //as an example, of course.
    }
    //And now for the fun part. Let's take the links and display them.
    //Making sure to automatically assign the pages to their respective chapters!
    //I've tested the below using given values (instead of fetching stuff)
    //and it worked fine. So I doubt this is causing it, but I kept it just in case.
    $rawChapters = returnConstants('CHAPTER');
    $chapters = array_values($rawChapters);
    $totalChapters = count($chapters);
    $chapterTitles = array();
    for ($i=1; $i<=$totalChapters; $i++) {
            $chapterTitles[] = "<h4>Chapter " . $i . ":</h4><p>";
            echo $chapterTitles[($i-1)];
            for ($j=1; $j<=$chapters[($i-1)]; $j++) {
                    echo array_shift($archiveLinks[($j-1)]);
            }
            echo "</p>"; //added to test if this was causing the deletion
    }
?>
```

What is causing the remainder of the document to vanish like that? **EDIT: Two silly syntax errors were causing this, and have been fixed in the above code! However, the links aren't being displayed at all?** Please note that I am pretty new to php and I do not expect my code to be the most efficient (I just want the darn thing to work!).

Addendum: if you deem to rewrite the code (instead of simply fixing error(s)) to be the preferred course of action, please do explain what the code is doing, as I do not like using code I do not understand. Thanks!

Comment: There's probably an error that's being hidden. What's your `error_reporting` level, and have you checked that the page otherwise works? Try using `require` instead of `include` and see if you get a fatal error

Comment: As above.  I have given you two syntax errors as an answer, but you really need to ensure that you have error reporting switched on (and to the highest level) as well as learn to check your logs.  See docs on `error_reporting` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @ChenAsraf I had two silly syntax errors causing the whole thing to wipe out. A prime reason not to write code when you haven't slept in several days (sadly that's when I tend to have my epiphanies!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having access to any of the rest of the code or data-structures I can see 2 syntax errors...

Line 45:

```
foreach ($pages = $page) {
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
```

Line 88:

```
echo array_shift($archiveLinks[($j-1)];
```

Is missing a bracket:

```
echo array_shift($archiveLinks[($j-1)]);
```

**Important...**

In order to ensure that you can find these kinds of errors yourself, you need to ensure that the error reporting is switched on to a level that means these get shown to you, or learn where your logs are and how to read them.

See the documentation on php.net here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

IMO all development servers should have the highest level of error reporting switched on by default so that you never miss an error, warning or notice.  It just makes your job a whole lot easier.

Documentation on setting up at runtime can be found here:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: I feel like a complete moron. I wrote that code at like 5 in the morning last week after nearly 60 hours without sleep. This fixed the display error completely. However, the script isn't producing the links properly. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please turn error_reporting to E_ALL in your development machine, and I'd suggest you learn how to debug and get a proper IDE to do so. You'll be saving yourself plenty of time (and on the long run, money) by doing so. As for the links not showing up properly, I'm sure if you debug you will go further than  us trying to understand the code from scratch. Good luck! :)

Comment: I agree with @ChenAsraf - now your immediate problem is fixed I suggest you go and try to debug yourself first and come back with a new question if you can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in `scripts/autodir.php` this file. Everything up to that point works fine, so this is where the problem starts.

Also you mostlikely have errors hidden as Chen Asraf mentioned, so turn on the errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Just put that at the top of the php file.

Comment: I'd say it's important that all development servers are set up to always show all errors, warnings and notices.  Whilst this does help with the immediate problem, I think it's worth pointing that out so that there isn't a repeat problem in a few hours time. (That sounds more critical than it's intended to be!)

Comment: I know I have (some) errors turned on at least because when I was messing around with a script last week it spit out a laundry list of errors. This one just did nothing, though. The mentioned lines turns on all error reporting for that file?